# Best Possible Way To add table in Android

Tags: android

I have to create table as shown in the image below in my app. What is the best possible way to do it?

How can i create a table like this? Any tutorial?
Which method would you choose to add this table?
I have to display this table tell me the best possible solution

**Another Question**

Suppose if i add this image in app, how can i add zooming feature? any tutorial?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried TableLayout?

Comment: @Eenvincible Yes but its quiet complex to add so much data through TableLayout

Comment: Have you learnt already anything about Adpaters or RecyclerView? If yes you need to make the first row and second which for you would be adapter and would be geneared with additional data ;-)

Comment: I would make each row an object and use an ArrayAdapter with a ListView. It's up to you on how you want to display the data in each item, though.

Answer (score 0):

Used Table Layout and also added margins/border using View check out the code below. Repeat the `<TableRow>` for adding more rows

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appBar2"
    android:paddingBottom="55dp"
    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
    android:paddingRight="2dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#000000" />

            <TableRow>
                <!-- Set the width to 0dp and set layout_weight=1! on both Views-->
                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#000000" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="DATE"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#000000" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="DAYS"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#000000" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="NO OF DAYS"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#000000" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="EVENT"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#000000" />
            </TableRow>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#000000" />
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```